# Prototype inheritance and extend existing objects

Tags: javascript, inheritance, call, prototype, extend

```
var Editor = {};

Editor.Basic = function(obj) {
    this.config ={
        value: obj
    }
};

Editor.Basic.prototype = {
    getValue: function() {
        return this.config.value;
    }
};

Editor.Advanced = function(obj) {
    Editor.Basic.call(this, obj);
};

Editor.Advanced.prototype = {
    config: {
        notValue: !this.config.value
    }
};

var extendByPrototype = function(obj1, obj2) {
    for (var key in obj2.prototype) {
        if (obj2.prototype.hasOwnProperty(key) && obj1.prototype[key] === undefined)
            obj1.prototype[key] = obj2.prototype[key];
    }
};

extendByPrototype(Editor.Advanced, Editor.Basic);
```

Is there anyway to get the `Editor.Advanced.prototype` to extend existing objects (recursively of course) instead of overriding them? (As seen in `extendByPrototype`)

I know I would check `obj1.prototype[key] !== undefined`, but I am unsure as what I need to do to extend existing keys in a generic way, without moving the `config` from `Editor.Advanced.prototype` to the constructor and using the `push` function.

Comment: You want a deep extend, jQuery has a (mediocre) algorithm

Comment: Hold on..let's check my understanding a bit. You're asking if there is way to make a Class object extends an instance object? Like how you're setting Editor.Advanced.prototype = { ... }?

Answer (score -1):

The proper way of extending an Object in JavaScript is using `Object.create(prototype)`. Objects created this way will have proper inheritance setup. To get the prototype of any object, you'll use `Object.getPrototypeOf(object)`.

`Object.create(prototype)` is new in JavaScript 1.8.5. If you're looking for backward compatible, you'll have to use the non-standard way

```
function extend(child, supertype) {  
  child.prototype.__proto__ = supertype.prototype;  
}  

extend(Animal, Lifeform);  
extend(Plant, Lifeform);  

var anOnion = new Plant();
```

After that, you can get the prototype object by...

```
object.contructor.__proto__
```

More details on `__proto__` here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto

Comment: Nobody should not use this example as a reference